# How to sort without using loop

Tags: c++, sorting, loops

How do I sort an array without using a loop in C++? I think it might use recursion, but I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: Can you describe why you want to do this and what you've tried so far? Do you mean "without any loops at all," or "without the main logic being a giant loop?" What research have you done into sorting algorithms? Please provide more description about your question, including your research effort.

Comment: Mergesort is a pretty well known divide and conquer recursive algorithm. Wikipedia and StackOverflow will be able to give you all the info you need on it. If you don't understand recursion, I would start there first.

Comment: Oh, the sounds of sorting... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67ta5WTjjUo&list=PLZh3kxyHrVp_AcOanN_jpuQbcMVdXbqei

Comment: Ok, but how to it implement without loop- using only recursion? I understand recursion more or less but I'd like to get code and anazlize it. It would be a great lesson.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) defined in **algorithm** header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a[]={5,3,4,1,2};
    sort(a,a+5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";         // 1 2 3 4 5
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int * sort(int *p,int i,int j,int size)
{
     if(i<size)
     { 
         if(j<size-i-1)
         {
             if(p[j]>p[j+1])
             {
                int temp = p[j];
                p[j] = p[j+1];
                p[j+1] = temp;
             }
        
    
         }
         else
         {
             j=-1;
             ++i;
         }

      p = sort(p,i,++j,size);
   }
   return p;
}
```

Below is how to use it

```
int  main()
{
    int array[] ={1,5,2,7,3};
    int len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
    int *a = sort(array,0,0,len);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
       printf("\n array[%d]->%d",i,a[i]);   
    }
}
```

Comment: if u find my answer correct and helpful so please vote my answer

Comment: How about you indent properly first?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. How about now ?

Comment: There is loop. as mentioned in question loops should not  be used

Comment: hardik hadwani... can't you see the loop is used just for printing not for sorting ... it is best practice to understand the code first.

Comment: @MonisMajeed, as you are setting j = 0 and passing ++j, there is chance it may fail. eg: {39, 32, 30, 11, 2}; will result in  array[0]->32
 array[1]->2
 array[2]->11
 array[3]->30
 array[4]->39 hence set j= -1 instaed of 0 in else part

Comment: @ Sujananth Visvaratnam it is pre-increment and not post increment so it will pass the value of j first and then increment the value of j.

Answer (score 1):

```
//C++
void bubblesort(vector<int> &arr, int iteration) {
    if(iteration == 0)
        return;

    bubbleswap(arr, 0, 1, iteration);
    bubblesort(arr, iteration-1);
}


void bubbleswap(vector<int> &arr, int i, int j, int n) {

    if(j>=n)
        return ;

    if(arr[i] < arr[j]){
        swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }

    bubbleswap(arr, i+1, j+1, n);
}


void sort(vector<int> &arr) {

    int n = arr.size();

    if(n<=1)
        return ;


    bubblesort(arr, n);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Recursive Selection Sort**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//----------------------------------------------------------
int recursive_min(vector<int>& a, size_t first) {
   //base case
   if (first + 1 >= a.size()) {
      return first;
   }
   else {
      size_t min_index {first};
      int temp_index {recursive_min(a, first + 1)};
      if (a[min_index] > a[temp_index]) {
         min_index = temp_index;
      }
      return min_index;
   }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------
void selectionSort(vector<int>& a, size_t step = 0) {
   //base case
   if (step + 1 >= a.size()) {
      return;
   }
   else {
      int temp_index {recursive_min(a, step + 1)};
      if (a[step] > a[temp_index]) {
         swap(a[step], a[temp_index]);
      }
      selectionSort(a, step + 1);
   }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
   vector<int> vec {11, 23, 2, 50, 3, 8, 1, 4, 5};
   selectionSort(vec);
   for (int i : vec) {
      cout << i << " ";
   }
}
```

**Recursive Insertion Sort**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int recursive_insert(vector<int>& a, int key, int i) {
   //base case
   if (i <= -1 || a[i] <= key) {
      return i;
   }
   else {
      a[i + 1] = a[i];
      return recursive_insert(a, key, i - 1);
   }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void insertion_sort(vector<int>& a, size_t j = 1) {
   //base case
   if (j >= a.size()) {
      return;
   }
   else {
      int key = a[j];
      int i = recursive_insert(a, a[j], j - 1);
      a[i + 1] = key;
      insertion_sort(a, j + 1);
   }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
   vector<int> vec {11, 23, 2, 50, 3, 8, 1, 4, 5};
   insertion_sort(vec);
   for (int i : vec) {
      cout << i << " ";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [Quicksort Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Comment: Depending on your definition of "without loops," a standard quicksort might not work because of the loop involved in the partitioning step.

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways to sort an array.

If you are trying to implement a loop recursively, you can check out a wikipedia article. It is well explained under "Recursion computer science". 
Otherwise you can try to implement different sorting algorithms. The well known are [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort).
There are many sorting algorithms

Comment: Ok, but how to it implement without loop- using only recursion? I understand recursion more or less but I'd like to get code and anazlize it. It would be a great lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm writing a Python interpreter and didn't write loop yet. I got the codebase from some website and rewrite the loop by some recursion. It works. :D

```
def quickSort(arr, low, high):
    def jLoop(low, high, pivot, i, j):
        if j >= high:
            temp = arr[high]
            arr[high] = arr[i+1]
            arr[i+1] = temp
            return (i+1)

        else:
            if arr[j] <= pivot:
                i = i+1
                temp = arr[i]
                arr[i] = arr[j]
                arr[j] = temp
            return jLoop(low, high, pivot, i, j+1)

    def partition(low, high):
        i = (low - 1)
        pivot = arr[high]
        return jLoop(low, high, pivot, i, low)

    def quick(low, high):
        if low < high:
            pi = partition(low, high)
            quick(low, pi-1)
            quick(pi+1, high)

    quick(low, high)

    return arr

my_list = [0, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 7, 5]
length = 8
print quickSort(my_list, 0, 7)

my_list = [9, 0, 8, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
length = 10
print quickSort(my_list, 0, 9)
```